# For an MVC site, how to get data/html from aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am to integrate an old aspx page into an MVC site where I can not modify the dll's from where the code behind comes from. I would prefer to use the same razor layout (cshtml) as for the rest of the site.

What I have access to change is the aspx page and it's controls (but not .cs-files).

I've seen [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)'s post about sharing masterpage, but that seems to apply for the other way around, where you use .master instead of .cshtml.

Apart from using an Iframe (which I prefer not to, because.. iframe) I've considered something along the lines of:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/page.aspx",
                success: function (msg) { $("#div").html(msg); }
            });
        });
```

But that will make the aspx page not work as expected considering postbacks etc.

EDIT: There's only this one aspx page that I'm going to use, that's not strictly MVC.

Any pointers on how one would go about and do this if there's even a way to achieve it? The functionality of this requirement is quite small in comparison, so rewriting it entirely to MVC is not possible.

Comment: They have too many differences. As far as the postback is concerned, you will not find it as it is not event driven anymore. You will not be able to map 1-1 for all your pages. And the way you are trying to implement will not make your application MVC.

Comment: @Anand how would you proceed to implement it? I want to keep my site MVC, but the client specifically requests this aspx page from a 3rd party and they do not support MVC.

Comment: There can be many ways to do it. Depending upon; 1) Why you want to change to MVC. 2) How much time you have 3) Complexity of the application 4) Available resources

Comment: I think you should use an `iframe` even though you don't want to. Like you said, if you `$.load` the aspx into the current page, they're not going to play nicely together because of the Webform's Postbacks. At least try an iframe first and then rule it out if there are technical reasons that it's not going to work.

Comment: Depending on the .aspx page layout and functionality maybe you'd be able to consum it as a service?

Comment: If moving the functionality from the main page is too much work, maybe it would be less work to create an ASP.NET master page that mimics the functionality of the Razor layout page...?

Comment: @NightOwl888 That is my fallback option as I see it. It will be harder to maintain, but it works.

Comment: @A3006 1) I'm not changing to MVC, the site is built in MVC and it's just that the client wants to integrate a specific system which only supports webforms.

Comment: @SteGriffiths I see your point. But then it comes down to never knowing the height of the iframe, since the content of the aspx page is dynamic (it's a searchable form that presents a result list).